# Directed Cycle Proof

Tags: graph-theory

Question: We have a diconnected directed graph with more than 2 nodes. 
Each node has indegree = 1 and outdegree = 1
Need to proof: The graph is directed cycle.

Is it correct to say that since each node has outdegree = one and each node has indegree = one, there is no other way to connect the nodes into a strongly connected graph?
Any other proof?

Thanks!

Comment: While it is correct to say that, it is not enough to say *only* that.  It still needs proof in my opinion.  As for a sketch to a proof, start with a vertex.  Since it has outdegree of $1$, pick what vertex it leads to.  Repeat this process.  Note that if you ever repeat a vertex before having used all of your vertices, then you have a closed cycle which doesn't involve all of the vertices which will eventually imply the graph is not in fact biconnected.  Reason then that you use all vertices in this process and finish by leading back to the original vertex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can prove this by induction on $n$. For $n=3$, it is clear that the only strongly connected digraph is the $3$-cycle. Now suppose for some $n\geqslant 3$ that the only strongly connected digraph on $n$ vertices is the $n$-cycle, denoted $C_n$. Adding a vertex $v$, we see that in order for $v$ to have indegree and outdegree $1$, there must be vertices $u,w\in C_n$ such that $uv$ and $vw$ are edges in $C_n\cup\{v\}$.

Now, if we add simply add these edges to the graph, then $u$ will have indegree $2$ and $w$ will have outdegree $2$, which is not acceptable. However, if $u$ and $w$ are adjacent, that is, $uw$ is an edge in $C_n$, then we can remove the edge $uw$ and then add the edges $uv$ and $vw$ and obtain $C_n\cup\{v,uv,vw\}\setminus\{uw\}=C_{n+1}$.

It perhaps remains to show that there is no other method of obtaining a strongly connected digraph with $n+1$ vertices from a strongly connected digraph with $n$ vertices. But I will leave that proof to you, if you are convinced it is necessary.